# Setting a Scheduled Task with Windows XP Home Edition

Tags: windows-xp, windows-task-scheduler

I wanted to use this command-line tool in a batch :

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC DAILY /TN "MySoftware" /TR mysoftware.exe /ST 02:00
```

to create a Scheduled Task on a client's computer (*I wanted to use a single batch that does everything for the client, rather than asking the client to have to manually add a Scheduled Task from Start Menu > ... > Task Scheduler*)

... but unfortunately, `SCHTASKS.EXE` isn't present on Windows XP Home Edition.

**What should I use to create a Scheduled Task on a client's computer (with WinXPHome), so that it's as easy as possible? (i.e. I don't want to ask the client to create the task manually)**

---

*Notes : 1) I have seen that there might be problems if the computer has a blank password (i.e. no password asked). How to be able to create a Task if the computer has no password protection ?*

*2) I have seen that `AT.EXE` may exist (I am not sure if it is present on Win XP Home?), but the Scheduled Task would not appear in the Start Menu > ... > Task Scheduler ; it seems to be a totally different system.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [schtasks in windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/524165/schtasks-in-windows-xp)

Comment: If @SeanCheshire 's link doesn't help, I believe the user could import the task as an .xml that you already have made for them. I'm not familiar enough to say for sure, but it may be as easy as placing that .xml in the correct directory.

Comment: @SeanCheshire the 2 answers of this question are not relevant for this specific question since 1) It is XP Home Edition. And copying the tool from another XP version is a dirty hack: if it is not present in XP Home, we don't have the license to just copy it from XP Pro. I cannot ask the client to do this.   2) The link given by the 2nd answer is obsolete (Error 404)

Comment: @Wutnaut: this would be great if we could just place a .xml somewhere!